# HttpURLConnection on android don't work on API under level 24

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I finish my app and it work well.
But I need to run it on an API 22 and under level 24 I don't know why my connection to my rest API doesn't work.

```
URL url = new URL(requeteUrl[0]);
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open

Log.d("TEST", ""+urlConnection.getHeaderFields());
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream()); // Stream
result = readStream(in); // Read stream
```

my log show that I have a code 400 but my url is good.
Also the minSdkVersion is set to 21 so it's not the problem.

Please can I have some help I don't want to buy a new device just for that.
thank

EDIT :

I have already the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the manifest.

And with the help of zeg I add `urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(new TLSSocketFactory());` for the TLS1.2 of my server but there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set internet usage permissions for your App inside your Manifest.xml like explained here https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting ?

Comment: Thank for the reply. Yes of course and I check if it's enabled ther no error from that normally

Comment: Since you say code 400 Bad Request that usually means you did open a request to a server but it was badly formed and the server responded that he can't handle it. What is the url you are trying to open? Does it work if you open it in a browser? Does the browser change the url to https automatically or something like that?

Comment: My url work in browser and with the same code in api level 24 and >. It's already in https and always the same.                                                                                    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> is good for all api level?

Comment: hard to tell... since you mentioned https you might want to check if your device has the appropriate ciphers installed that are supported by your webserver. some webservers allow only new and strong security ciphers for the tls/ssl https handshake and deny clients that do not support them...?

Comment: try to query the ciphers on your webserver something like this `nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.example.com`

Comment: where can I write this code? I try in linux he can't find the url EDIT: it's work and it's TLSv1.2

Comment: you propably need to apt install nmap before :) it is a web scanning tool

Comment: Is all the android os on api under level 24 use an other TLS?

Comment: I check and I found that 'Android is officially supporting TLSv1.2 since Android 5.0 (API level 20)'. I think it's not the problem.

Comment: ciphers not protocoll :) each protocoll has a subgroup of ciphers. see here https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers

Comment: Well your newer device with the exact same code works. So it has to be a device thing. Http 400 tells you that you reached the server but the server didn't liked what you was asking for, so you can send something but it looks odd. Since it is the same code it is not about the request but something prios - meaning TLS handshake or some proxy header filtering which i doubt you to do on mobile.

Comment: i think the webadmin of your url enforce strong ciphers, for example TLS1.2 with diffie hellmannn elliptic curve only. Your new device is setup to use that, however your old device might support only TLS 1.2 with preshared RSA secret or normal diffie hellmann key exchange. Maybe it is the key exchange, maybe the checksum, i don't know it is all annotated in the cipher specification

Comment: i hope that helps somewhat. i know device stuff is wayyyy more struggling than fixing bugs in your code. :) good luck

Comment: Well it's my api and I use hostinger I don't know if it's can help 

Comment: Yeah it's hard I know my wifi leave me I'm not lucky today

Comment: Maybe it is something similiar to this issue: https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/ssl-version-cipher-mismatch-error

Comment: Thank a lot I will check that when my wifi come back. Hope it will work.

Comment: I check all the ciphers and it's some TLS ECDHE RSA WITH AES or TLS RSA WITH AES with sha and rsa. I make my device the default cipher suite to support this with my TLSSocketFactory. But there is the same code 400. Now I'm not sure that it's the problem.

Comment: Strange... The exact same code works on another device correct?

Comment: Yeah finally it was an error of url cause the api 22 change the \n in space something like this